# Facebook says app_id is invalid

Tags: html, facebook

I am trying to install insights on my website, http://www.luof.co.uk and have verified that it is indeed the same ID, however, I get this message...

"The app ID "XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX" specified within the "fb:app_id" meta tag was invalid."

Any ideas why this is happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no `fb:app_id` meta tag on the page you linked - only `fb:admins` is present.

Add the meta tag and it should start working, see Facebook's [getting started guides](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/insights/) for step by step instructions.

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="user_id" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="your_app_id" />
```

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the insight (sorry for the pun!). but I just copied what Facebook told me to, which was "<meta property="fb:admins" content="XXXX" />", then press "Get Insights", then that error message comes up. Have already looked through the Facebook developer pages and followed the instructions. Hope that helps!

Comment: Strange - it looks like it may have given you the wrong ID, then. The URL Debugger reports that the ID is invalid (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=www.luof.co.uk), and indeed the ID specified in your code is for https://www.facebook.com/londonusedofficefurniture - whereas it should be your Facebook user id. Try manually changing the value to your user id and see if it works.

Comment: Got an update, the error message is now... "Logged in user not authorised to view this domain."... What I done, was created an App as the page admin, then put the URL into there. Now the page isn't "authorised" to view the domain. Nearly there though I think! :)